# Prolog Program not exiting

Tags: prolog

I've written prolog program which takes initial, pickup and final (x,y,z) coordinates. The agent should reach the final coordinates through the pickup coordinates. When I run the query, the program runs indefinitely. I'm assuming this is because there are a huge number of combinations to search through. So i decreased my constraints in `in_range(X,Y,Z)`. I'm new to prolog, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
in_range(X,Y,Z):-
        X > -5,
        X < 5,
        Y >= 0,
        Y < 10,
        Z > -5,
        Z < 5.

deliver(Ix,Iy,Iz,Px,Py,Pz,Fx,Fy,Fz):-
        in_range(Ix,Iy,Iz),
        in_range(Px,Py,Pz),
        in_range(Fx,Fy,Fz),
        move(Ix,Iy,Iz,Px,Py,Pz),
        move(Px,Py,Pz,Fx,Fy,Fz).

move(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2):-
        X is X1-1,
        Y is Y1,
        Z is Z1,
        in_range(X,Y,Z),
        X =:= X2,
        Y =:= Y2,
        Z =:= Z2;
        X is X1-1,
        Y is Y1,
        Z is Z1,
        in_range(X,Y,Z),
        move(X,Y,Z,X2,Y2,Z2).

move(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2):-
        X is X1,
        Y is Y1-1,
        Z is Z1,
        in_range(X,Y,Z),
        X =:= X2,
        Y =:= Y2,
        Z =:= Z2;
        X is X1,
        Y is Y1-1,
        Z is Z1,
        in_range(X,Y,Z),
        move(X,Y,Z,X2,Y2,Z2).

move(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2):-
        X is X1,
        Y is Y1,
        Z is Z1-1,
        in_range(X,Y,Z),
        X =:= X2,
        Y =:= Y2,
        Z =:= Z2;
        X is X1,
        Y is Y1,
        Z is Z1-1,
        in_range(X,Y,Z),
        move(X,Y,Z,X2,Y2,Z2).

move(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2):-
        X is X1+1,
        Y is Y1,
        Z is Z1,
        in_range(X,Y,Z),
        X =:= X2,
        Y =:= Y2,
        Z =:= Z2;
        X is X1+1,
        Y is Y1,
        Z is Z1,
        in_range(X,Y,Z),
        move(X,Y,Z,X2,Y2,Z2).

move(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2):-
        X is X1,
        Y is Y1+1,
        Z is Z1,
        in_range(X,Y,Z),
        X =:= X2,
        Y =:= Y2,
        Z =:= Z2;
        X is X1,
        Y is Y1+1,
        Z is Z1,
        in_range(X,Y,Z),
        move(X,Y,Z,X2,Y2,Z2).

move(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2):-
        X is X1,
        Y is Y1,
        Z is Z1+1,
        in_range(X,Y,Z),
        X =:= X2,
        Y =:= Y2,
        Z =:= Z2;
        X is X1,
        Y is Y1,
        Z is Z1+1,
        in_range(X,Y,Z),
        move(X,Y,Z,X2,Y2,Z2).

move(6,_,_,_,_,_).
move(-6,_,_,_,_,_).
move(_,11,_,_,_,_).
move(_,-1,_,_,_,_).
move(_,_,6,_,_,_).
move(_,_,-6,_,_,_).
```

The query I'm running is

```
?-deliver(0,0,0,1,1,1,4,4,4).
```

Comment: Most likely you're looping, visiting the *same* coordinate again and again. If you're running a *very* recent version of SWI-Prolog, use tabling

Comment: Thanks, it was looping through the same coordinates again and again. I was able to get a output by removing functions to decrement the coordinates. Is there anyway i can add the decrement portion of the code without causing a infinite loop.

Comment: the easier way is to use tabling, that is, `:- table move/6.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting an infinite recursion because you're doing a depth-first search without tracking visited nodes, by tracing it you'll see for the example that your search gets lost in a (0, 0, 4) <> (0, 0, 5) loop, based on the first move predicate.

Tabling will work for SWI-Prolog, but let's take this opportunity to explore portable solutions as they'll aid your Prolog (and broader CS) learning.

First, let's look at that `in_range/3` predicate and turn our locations into terms (if you bump into the word "reification", this is doing that). We want to consider our locations as terms so we can pass them around as whole entities. It also helps us think! We can define what a location is in your world like so:

```
% loc(X, Y, Z) is a location in 3D integer co-ordinate space
loc(X, Y, Z) :- 
    between(-5, 5, X), 
    between(0, 10, Y), 
    between(-5, 5, Z).
```

Thus `in_range/3` becomes `in_range/1`:

```
in_range(Loc) :- call(Loc).
```

As a bonus, you can generate locations: `?- loc(X, Y, Z).`

Now those move predicates can be tidied up to make them much easier to read, trace and think about. To that end, they only define a single move, best to keep journeys 
to their own predicate so we can use these individually when we only want a single step. (`?- move(loc(1, 1, 2), Step).`)

```
%! move(Loc1, Loc2)
move(loc(X1, Y, Z), loc(X2, Y, Z)) :- X2 is X1 + 1, in_range(loc(X2, Y, Z)).
move(loc(X1, Y, Z), loc(X2, Y, Z)) :- X2 is X1 - 1, in_range(loc(X2, Y, Z)).
move(loc(X, Y1, Z), loc(X, Y2, Z)) :- Y2 is Y1 + 1, in_range(loc(X, Y2, Z)).
move(loc(X, Y1, Z), loc(X, Y2, Z)) :- Y2 is Y1 - 1, in_range(loc(X, Y2, Z)).
move(loc(X, Y, Z1), loc(X, Y, Z2)) :- Z2 is Z1 + 1, in_range(loc(X, Y, Z2)).
move(loc(X, Y, Z1), loc(X, Y, Z2)) :- Z2 is Z1 - 1, in_range(loc(X, Y, Z2)).
```

Now let's define our delivery predicate. `in_range/1` can be used to check the `From` is valid, whereas `Pickup` and `Dest` are expected to take care of that themselves:

```
deliver(From, Pickup, Dest) :-
    in_range(From),
    go_to(From, Pickup),
    go_to(Pickup, Dest).
```

So far I've only refactored your code to break predicates down into smaller definitions for more versatility and easier readability. The big change to prevent the infinite recursion is in `go_to/2`, which is not yet defined. Given that you're doing a search in integer 3D coordinate space, the most suitable search algorithm is A*, which will not only exclude search locations already visited, but will first search locations closest to the intended goal.

```
go_to(Origin, Destination) :-
    a_star(Origin, Destination).

% A* for SWI-Prolog
:- use_module(library(heaps)).

% Use to order search, 3D euclidean distance squared
heuristic_distance(loc(X1, Y1, Z1), loc(X2, Y2, Z2), Distance) :-
    Distance is (X1 - X2)^2 + (Y1 - Y2)^2 + (Z1 - Z2)^2.

% Add a list of nodes to the heap
open_add_nodes(Heap, [], _, Heap).
open_add_nodes(Heap, [ToAdd|Tail], Dest, Out) :-
    heuristic_distance(ToAdd, Dest, Dist),
    add_to_heap(Heap, Dist, ToAdd, Heap1),
    open_add_nodes(Heap1, Tail, Dest, Out).

% Get an ordered list of reachable locations from the origin
get_reachable(Loc, Locations) :-
    setof(L, move(Loc, L), Locations).

% A* search setup
a_star(Origin, Dest) :-
    % Create heap of open search nodes
    heuristic_distance(Dest, Origin, Dist),
    singleton_heap(Open, Dist, Origin),
    % Do the search
    a_star(Open, Dest, [Origin]).

% Do the A* search
a_star(Open, Dest, Closed) :-
    % Get the most promising Node
    get_from_heap(Open, _, Loc, RemainingSearch),
    % If we've reached the goal, return the Answer
    (   Dest = Loc
    % Otherwise keep searching
    ;   get_reachable(Loc, ReachableLocations),
        % Exclude visited nodes
        ord_union(Closed, ReachableLocations, Closed1, ToSearch),
        % Add new open nodes to search heap
        open_add_nodes(RemainingSearch, ToSearch, Dest, Open1),
        % Carry on searching
        a_star(Open1, Dest, Closed1)
    ).
```

Now A* might take a bit to read and understand, but it'd be much more difficult if we were having to deal with the `X, Y, Z` coordinates than with locations: every `Loc`, `Dest`, `Origin` and `ToAdd` is a location. It's also only possible to code because our `move/2` predicate only takes a single step, so we *can* choose not to use Prolog's implicit Depth-First Search.

All this code is in a [SWISH Notebook](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/57642732/prolog-program-not-exiting.pl) so you can explore it. To learn more about search algorithms I'd recommend the [MIT AI lectures on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1H3jAAGlEA&list=PLUl4u3cNGP63gFHB6xb-kVBiQHYe_4hSi&index=4), 4 and 5 cover search. For Prolog implementations, ["The Craft of Prolog"](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/craft-prolog), also out of MIT, is excellent.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis and answer. I'll check the links you have provided.